# Intent and Edit Text Issues

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am basically trying to create an application which consists of 2 activities.
In activity 1 , user can enter 2 values in 2 separate edit text fields and I have provided a spinner drop down item , using which user can select either of 2 values.

If user selects option as 1 and clicks on Submit button , user will be displayed a second activty with value displayed as per the id selected in spinner object in previous activity.

Like if user selects 1 , value in first edit text box gets shown and if he selects 2 , then second edit text box value is displayed.

Also, when user clicks on submit button in second activity , based on value he enters in edit text field of second activity , it will get displayed in either edit text box 1 or edit text box 2 of previous activity .

I am having issues understanding why my app is showing bizarre behaviour. Please guide me.

FIRST ACTIVITY FILE:

```
package spinnner.intents.understand;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Spinner;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;

    public class TwoAppsActivity extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        String [] items = {"1","2"}; 
        //String ch;
        TextView tv;
        EditText et1,et2;
        Spinner spinner;    
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

             tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
            et1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittxt1); // value 1
            et2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittxt2); // value 2
            spinner=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin1); // select

            // 

            Intent i3 = getIntent();
            if(i3.getStringExtra("spinner.intents.understand.value1")!=null)
            {
                et1.setText(i3.getStringExtra("spinner.intents.understand.value1"));
            }
            else if(i3.getStringExtra("spinner.intents.understand.value2")!=null)
            {
                et2.setText(i3.getStringExtra("spinner.intents.understand.value2"));
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter some text ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

         // spinner logic
            ArrayAdapter<String> as1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);
            as1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner.setAdapter(as1);
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    tv.setText(items[arg2]);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " You selected : "+items[arg2],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You selected nothing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

            //
        }

        public void Submit(View v)
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(this,Second.class);
            startActivity(i);



            //str1 = et1.getText().toString();
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), str1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //  str2 = et2.getText().toString();
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), str2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            //




            if(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString()=="1")
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I am in 1st option", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                i.putExtra("spinner.intents.understand.value1", et1.getEditableText().toString()); 
                i.putExtra("spinner.intents.understand.Id1", "1");
            }
            else if(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString()=="2")
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I am in 2nd option", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                i.putExtra("spinner.intents.understand.value2", et2.getEditableText().toString());
                i.putExtra("spinner.intents.understand.Id2", "2");
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You selected nothing!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }



        }
    }
```

SECOND ACTIVITY FILE

```
  package spinnner.intents.understand;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class Second extends Activity{
          /** Called when the activity is first created. */
            TextView Tv;
            EditText Et;
            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.second);
                //
                Tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtS1);
                Et=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittxtS1);
                //

                Intent i1 = getIntent();                               

                if((i1.getStringExtra("spinner.intents.understand.Id1"))=="1")
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I am in value 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();               
                    Et.setText(i1.getStringExtra("spinner.intents.understand.value1"));             
                }           
                else if((i1.getStringExtra("spinner.intents.understand.Id2"))=="2")
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I am in value 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Et.setText(i1.getStringExtra("spinner.intents.understand.value2"));
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Some mismatch", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }

            public void submit(View v)
            {
                Intent i2 = new Intent(this,TwoAppsActivity.class);
                startActivity(i2);
                if(i2.getStringExtra("Id1")=="1")
                {
                    i2.putExtra("spinner.intents.understand.value1", Et.getEditableText().toString());

                }
                else if(i2.getStringExtra("Id2")=="2")
                {
                    i2.putExtra("spinner.intents.understand.value2", Et.getEditableText().toString());

                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No data to display", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
    }
```

MAIN.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt1"
        android:text="Enter value 1:"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/edittxt1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt2"
        android:text="Enter value 2:"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/edittxt2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txt3"
        android:text="Select"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Spinner 
        android:id="@+id/spin1"        
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btnsubmit1"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:onClick="Submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

SECOND ACTIVITY XML FILE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txtS1"
        android:text="Value:"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/edittxtS1"        
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btnsubmit2"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:onClick="submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

ANDROID MANIFEST XML FILE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="spinnner.intents.understand"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".TwoAppsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity 
            android:name=".Second">            
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I am also willing to mail my project if my code appears too messed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use == nor != to compare two strings. Use equals instead:

```
if(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("1"))
```

Regards.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but still my app shows bizarre behaviour.I mean it doesn't work properly.

Comment: I mean when I use equals my first activity works but when I click on submit , it does not go to next activity but force closes. :(

Comment: Another issues is that you call startActivity() before setting the extra, so the new activity can't receive it, causing a uncaughted NullPointerException, crashing the app.

Comment: Submit method in Second activity appears very strange because you create a new Intent, i2, and then test the value of an extra called Id1, that obviously can't exist since the intent is new, causing another NPE. Maybe you should test the received Intent using getIntent() instead creating a new one.

Comment: I request someone please send me their email id.I modified my code.Now having other issues.The reason is it will be difficult to update here new errors and changes in code since I almost everyday rectify my code.